# Dirac functions, inner products and $T \in \mathcal{L}(G)$

Tags: group-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, operator-algebras, orthonormal

If 
G is a countable group with neutral element e (and with the composition written multiplicatively).

$\ell^2(G)$ consist of functions $x: G \to \mathbb{C} $ such that $\sum_{t \in G} \vert x(t) \vert^2 < \infty$ and with inner product

\begin{equation}
\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{t \in G} x(t) \overline{y(t)}
\end{equation}
For $x,y \in \ell^2(G)$.

For each $t \in G$ let $\delta_t \in \ell^2(G)$ be given by $\delta_t (t) = 1$ and $\delta_t(s)=0$ whenever $s \neq t$. \

The set $\lbrace \delta_t \rbrace_{t \in G}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\ell^2 (G) $ and

\begin{equation}
x(t)= \langle x , \delta_t \rangle
\end{equation}

For $x \in \ell^2(G)$ and $t \in G$.

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(G)$ be given and put $x = T \delta_e \in \ell^2 (G)$

(i) Show that $x(t)= \langle T \delta_s , \delta_{ts} \rangle$ for all $s,t \in G$

Idea: I believe that the orthonormality part is essential, as every element x in $\ell^2 (G) $ can thus be written as $\sum_{t \in G} \langle x, \delta_t \rangle \delta_t$,  right? However, what I have tried so far gives me that

$x(t)=\langle x, \delta_t \rangle = \langle T \delta_e, \delta_t \rangle = \sum_{t \in G} T \delta_e (t) \overline{\delta_t (t)}$ 
However, I can't see how this will get me any further.

Comment: Please read the post [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|127.1402), and afterwards, please return to this post, click on edit, and improve it accordlingly.  Notice, in particular, the portion devoted to "I have not clue" questions, or "I'm completely stuck.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by $\mathcal L(G)$ you mean the group von-Neumann algebra of $G$ (if this is stated somewhere in your question, I couldn't find it).  In this case, fix $s,t\in G$, approximate $T$ by an element $T_0\in\mathbb CG$ in the weak operator topology, and show that we have 
$$(T_0\delta_e)(t)=\langle T_0\delta_s,\delta_{ts}\rangle$$  (The idea here being that the left- and right-regular representations of $G$ on $\ell^2(G)$ commute.)